# Struts2 s:if test for non-null value

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl

I am wanting to test for a non-null value using a struts2  tag.  This works if I use the following:

```
<s:if test="myObject.myField != null">..stuff..</s:if>
```

It also seems to work if I miss out the not-null part, and just do:

```
<s:if test="myObject.myField">..stuff..</s:if>
```

However, when `myField` is a `String`, this no longer works.  I prefer the second form as it is more concise, and seems less like putting code in my presentation layer. But I don't want to use it if it's an undocumented feature which is somehow *working by accident*, as suggested by the fact that it doesn't work for strings.

So my question is, is it ever ok to miss out `"!= null"` in the above test?

Answer (score 0):

Using `<s:if test="whatsoever` the `whatsoever` is an OGNL expression that should evaluate to `Boolean` value if you want the tag is working right. If your field is of `boolean` type it's ok, in other case it's just doesn't work.

Also, in the documentation page for the [`if` tag](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/if-tag.html) the type is defined as `Boolean`, so it's not primitive `boolean` but the value could be primitive `boolean`.  So, be careful when using different types when evaluating the test case.

Comment: Thanks, testing my code shows that it does work though, in that I get the same output with or without the "!= null", in both the null and the non-null case.

Comment: Now it's time to accept and upvote  the answer. The checkbox is on the left of the answer.