# Using javascript's return value as condition in a struts if tag

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, struts2

I am working on formatting HTML with struts2 and javascript, and am passing the return value of a function to a `<s:if>` tag. I would expect it to behave like any other conditional; however, the `<s:if>` tag consistently behaves as though it is returning `false`.

**page.jsp**

```html
<s:if test="%{myFunction()}">
  <p>foo</p>
</s:if>
<s:else>
  <p>bar</p>
</s:else>
```

**page.js**

```js
function myFunction() {
  if(some_condition) { return true; }
  else { return false; }
}
```

> bar

I've tested the javascript function independently, and it's working as intended - both `true` and `false` are being returned depending on the conditions. The function is being properly included in the `.jsp` code (it's defined earlier in a `<script>` tag).

Intuitively, I believe I should be able to use the return value as a conditional, but I'm beginning to believe I might be incorrect. Documentation on this behavior is rather sparse, and the [official struts2 documentation](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/components/If.html) doesn't have much to say on whether it's possible or not.

Is this a syntax error, or have I run into a limit of struts2?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22248867/573032

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is neither (1) a syntax error nor (2) a "limitation" of Struts 2.

1. If it was a syntax error you'd get... a syntax error, either on the server side in the logs, or on the client side in the JS console.
2. S2 is a standard action-based Java web framework; it knows nothing about anything on the client side: there is no (direct) interop between what happens on the server and what happens on the client (e.g., browser).

**TL;DR:** JSP pages run on the server. JavaScript runs on the client. There's no direct connection.

Pages sent to the client are rendered *before* being sent, *before* any JavaScript is run, etc. The server side knows nothing about the JavaScript on your page. (That's why you can render S2 tags into JS that the code then uses once it's on the client.)

If you want to be able to dynamically render DOM elements then everything has to be handled on the JS side, although your JS code can include S2 tags.

This is basic Java web app stuff: JSP files are just templates. They are completely rendered before being sent to the client as the response.

Comment: You ever get that feeling where you know there's something *huge* you've been missing, but it's something so obvious you'd never think of it 'till it's pointed out? This was it - I've been assuming JSP is rendered client-side the same way HTML did, and I didn't even realize it was being processed server-side first. JS not being usable in a struts2 tag makes perfect sense now, because by the time it gets to the point where it would check the function, it's already at the client, and the rendering decision has already been made. Thank you for the explanation; I'd upvote this twice if I could.

Comment: @NickReed I have that feeling 4-5x daily, more if you ask my friends. But yep--your paraphrasing hits the nail on the head.