# getting null while using request.setattriubute value in struts2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts

I am working on struts2 but getting issue in the jsp while accessing a variable in form class using a set variable inside property tag.

Please find the below full code.

#### Testactionform.java

```
public class Testactionform {
    String name = "india";

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

#### TestAction.java

```
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware;

public class TestAction implements SessionAware
{
    public Testactionform test;
    public Testactionform getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(Testactionform test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

    private Map<String, Object> session;
    
    public Map<String, Object> getSession() {
        return session;
    }

    public void setSession(Map<String, Object> session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

    public String execute() 
    {
        final HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
        test=new Testactionform();
        request.setAttribute("name1", "name");
        test.setName("london");
        session.put("Testactionform",test);
        System.out.println("execute() method called");
        return"success";
    }
}
```

#### Success.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>error page</h1>
<s:set var="name2" value="#request.name1"></s:set>
<s:property value="%{#session.Testactionform.name2}"/>
</body>
</html>
```

In JSP with below line, I want to access the `name` variable in `Testactionform`, but I get nothing in the response.

```
<s:property value="%{#session.Testactionform.name2}"/>
```

Comment: Replace `session.put("helloform","helloform")` with `session.put("helloform",helloform)` assuming `helloform` is an object which you want to put into session with the key, `helloform`.

Comment: yes i have replaced that but it is still not working.

Comment: can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: It is very strange that you are trying access a variable which doesn't exist on the form. If you don't know a variable exists or not then to prevent `null` values printed use `if` tag. For more details look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22248867/573032) answer.

Comment: It's unclear what the issue is, or what code is actually being executed, or anything about the form. I'm also de-tagging Struts 1 since there seems to be nothing related to Struts 1 here at all.

Comment: Dave please accept my apology for my unclear question i have update the code .Could you please look into it and help me resolve my issue?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the command which is working fine for me .

**<s:property value="#session.Testactionform[#name2]"/>**